# Engagement Split after a Line message activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

me and my team were wondering if the Engagement Split activity in Journey builder could track also LINE message opens into a journey.

We could not find this information anywhere, has anyone ever came across to this topic?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Engagement splits in JB are only supporting email messaging